Circular Motion in Isolated Ring and Bead system about COM
The problem i was solving was as follows

A small bead of mass $m = 4.0\hspace{1mm}kg$ is threaded on a homogeneous friction-less ring of mass $M = 6.0\hspace{1mm}kg$ and radius $R = 0.5\hspace{1mm}m$. Initially the system is at rest in free space. Now the bead is struck to impart it a velocity $u = 5.0\hspace{1mm}m/s$ along the tangent to the ring. Find the magntiude of a force of interaction between the ring and the bead, and the minimum kinetic energy of the bead in the subsequent motion.

The solution, i came up with gave me the correct answer but i doubt how correct it is, basically i assumed the center of mass of the ring and the bead would go around the center of mass of the both in circular motion and using $mv^2/r$ to get the force of interaction.
However i could not find the minimum kinetic energy, when i looked at the solution to the problem it was mentioned that the minimum velocity of the bead would be the difference between the velocity of the bead in the COM frame and the velocity of the COM.
I could not understand why this would be true, and secondly is my assumption even correct?, any help would be highly appreciated!

Is the ring anchored in any way or just free floating in space?

@KDP No it is not anchored it is just threaded to a ring which is free floating in space

After the velocity is imparted there will be interaction forces between the two( I am assuming you are not asked about this force in the question). After some time system will come to a certain state and remain forever in this state. That state is rotation of bead and COM of the ring around the Total COM of both+ translation of total COM at constant V say $V_{COM}$. You can calculate $V_{COM}$, the distance of COM wrt to the bead, and the velocity of bead wrt to COM(energy conservation) and hence get interaction force(centripetal force).

The bead is performing Rotational(around COM) + Translational motion(with velocity $V_{COM}$). The minimum speed of an object performing Rotational + translational is = |$V_{rotational} - V_{translational}$|. Where $V_{rotational}$ is the velocity of bead in COM frame
